# Filter current year from csv

Tags: python, csv, datetime

How can I use `dateime` to automatically input the current year into my filter and have the file that's created from the filter named with the current year too?

Where it says "2015" I'm trying to have that change with the current year. The data in the csv is in a M/DD/YYYY format

```
import csv
import time
from datetime import date

reader = csv.reader(open(r"input.csv"),delimiter=',')
filtered = filter(lambda p: '2015' == p[7], reader)
csv.writer(open(r'output\Year\2015.csv','w', newline =''),delimiter=',').writerows(filtered)
time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: [datetime.now()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now) with subsequent `.year` property

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `date.today().year`:

```
import csv
import time
from datetime import date

year = str(date.today().year)
filename = r'output\Year\{}.csv'.format(year)
reader = csv.reader(open(r"input.csv"),delimiter=',')
filtered = filter(lambda p: year == p[7], reader)
csv.writer(open(filename, 'w', newline=''), delimiter=',').writerows(filtered)
time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: What about `year` in the `lambda` passed to `filter`?

Comment: I actually completely missed that `year` was used twice, good catch

Comment: @malbarbo the date in row 7 is in a MM/DD/YYYY format, does `(lambda p: year == p[7], reader)` need to be changed to read the year properly? Its generating the files with the year but with no data. Everything else is working now though, thanks so much.

Comment: Get the last 4 chars `p[7][-4:]`